# Python mechanize loses attributes on second open

Tags: python, mechanize

This is a really specialized case and I feel awkward asking it; however I'm at wits end working on it.

I need to follow a tracking number through a form and to a results page so I've been using mechanize in python, the link after form submission is embedded in javascript so I can't simply follow_link. What I want to do is to regex out the url and then ask call `open()` on that, however when I do - I run into some problems.

I can call `br.geturl()` and `br.title()` just fine on the target page, but when it comes time to read the source of the page in question, it throws

```
AttributeError: mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance has no attribute read (perhaps you forgot to .select_form()?)
```

Is there some way to do this or am I monkey-patching it too much, any advice would be terrific

edit [more code {really ugly just trying to get it to work}]:

```
cosn="########"
baseurl="http://aaa.com/"
search="thing.do"

br=Browser()
br.open(baseurl+search)
br.select_form('traceForm')
br['consignments']=cosn
req=br.submit()
pars=Soup(req.read())
found_url=re.match(r"javascript:window.location.href = '(?P<url>[\w\d=&?\.]+)", pars.find('td', attrs={'class':'select'})['onclick']).group('url')

br.open(baseurl+found_url)
print br.title()  # works
print br.geturl()  # works
print br.read()  # throws exception
```

Comment: Could you post some more code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never make *first*  `.read` method call on Browser instance. That's because it doesn't have such method. The `Browswer.response` has `read` method, so if you want to get the body of response you'd need to do:

```
response = br.response()
response.read()
```

For the future, you could use `dir(obj)` to see the content of the object `obj`, be it browser or anything else.

Comment: thank you so much, I knew what I was doing was wrong but I was feeling helpless with the mechanize documentation